# Simulation user click Arrow DOWN button not working，Page does not scroll

Tags: javascript

```js
window.document.body.focus()
var event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
    key: 'ArrowDown',
    keyCode: 40,
    which: 40,
    code: 'ArrowDown'
  });
  document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

I hope to simulate the effect of user keyboard operation using scripts

Any website. Because I manually click on the arrow down button and it scrolls

Comment: Is the body of your html scrollable? Please edit your question and add the HTML code.

Comment: I don't know if that really works like that to scroll a page by dispatching an event. I would rather listen to ``keydown`` and then apply a scroll directly via a reference to the element in js

Comment: Any website. Because I manually click on the arrow down button and it scrolls

Comment: did this ever work? I didn't try this but it might be that browser shortcuts are not available to websites. You can't also trigger an `alt + F4` event to close browser window.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.